# Ubuntu Aquaris 4.5 battery sometimes runs down quickly when not in use?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, power-management, battery, phone

Checking the battery use for the Ubuntu phone Aquaris4.5 it shows an almost flat line when not used (wifi enabled, otherwise all the battery saving settings used) Occasionally (3times in the last week) the battery is dead although there was plenty of charge when I last used it.
Last night the charge was 35% and was dead when I got up. 
ps I like the phone, even with all its bugs apart from this one.

Comment: The same thing was happening to me as well and the weirdest part is that it keeps happening even after I replaced the Ubuntu with Android. I thought I had a defective battery but it seems other people suffer from it as well plus as you already mentioned it happens only if the phone is left idle for a longer period.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a tool to determine what kinds of events prevent the Ubuntu phone from going into deep sleep.  I believe the tool is shipped on the current images.

You need to get access to a terminal and run:

```
suspend-blocker -bHr < /var/log/syslog
```

..and this will identify the reasons for the wakeups from deep sleep and the deep sleep profile.

For more information, see: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/suspend-blocker